# AWS EMR Hadoop Administration

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

We are currently using Apache Hadoop (Vanilla Version) in our org. We are planning to migrate to AWS EMR. I'm trying to understand how AWS EMR Hadoop works internally (not how to use it), I'm mainly interested in Hadoop administration steps and how master and slave communicates and various configuration configurations. I already checked the AWS EMR documentation but I don't see detailed comparison.

Can someone recommend me a link/tutorial for migrating to AWS EMR from an Apache Hadoop.

Comment: has your team looked at Qubole? We have had many customers move over from in-house Hadoop as well as EMR and benefited a lot from auto-scaling, spot instance integration and just superior performance and management in general.

Answer (score 1):

During EMR cluster creation, it will ask you to specify Master and Node. a default settings will provision 1 master and two nodes for you. You can also specify what all applications you want to be in the cluster (e.g.: hadoop, hive, spark, zeppelin, hue, etc.).

Once the cluster is created, it will provision all the services. you can click on these services and access them via web, or using ssh into the master. For e.g: to access the ambari interface, go to the service within EMR and click it. a new window will be launched with the ambari monitoring service interface.

Installing these applications is very easy. all you have to do is specify all the services while cluster creation.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Elastic MapReduce uses a mostly standard implementation of Hadoop and associated tools.

See: [AMI Versions Supported in Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/ami-versions-supported.html)

The benefits of using EMR are in the automated deployment of instances. For example, launching a cluster with an appropriate AMI means that software is already loaded on each instance and HDFS is configured across the core nodes.

The Master and Slave (Core/Task) nodes communicate in exactly the normal way that they communicate in any Hadoop cluster. However, only one Master is supported (with no backup Master).

When migrating to EMR, check that you are using compatible versions of software (eg Hadoop, Hive, Pig, Impala, etc). Also consider using Amazon S3 for storage of data instead of HDFS, especially for storing source data, since data on S3 persists even after the EMR cluster is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, Hadoop provided with EMR, can be few releases back. You should check EMR release notes for detailed application provided with each version.  EMR takes care application provisioning, setup and configuration. Based on EC2 instance type, Hadoop (and other application configuration) will change. You can override default settings using configure application.

Other than this Hadoop you have on premises and EMR should be the same.